# Warnings or errors for C++ implicit conversion of primitives

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I've done some heavy refactoring of some C++ code, and discovered numerous bugs arising from implicit conversions that I'm not aware of.

### Example

```
struct A *a();

bool b() {
    return a();
}

void c() {
    int64_t const d(b());
}
```

### Issues

1. In `b`, the return type of `a` is silently cast to `bool`.
2. In `c`, the value returned from `b` is silently promoted to `int64_t`.

### Question

**How can I receive warnings or errors for the implicit conversion between primitive types**?

### Note

1. The use of `-Wconversion` seems to only pick up several arbitrary conversions unrelated to the example above.
2. [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp) is not an option (my types need to be PODs, as they're used in disk structures).
3. C is also of interest, however this problem pertains to a C++ code base.

Comment: I do not know if -Wextra will warn about these, but generally if you want to get more diagnostics and find more questionable places in your code then try to build it on several compilers with extensions turned off and all warnings turned on. For example gcc, icc and clang. You will certainly find more issues.

Comment: what version of gcc are you using ?

Comment: Both casts are standard compliant, so a compiler should not warn about them. Try a staticc code analyzer. See also the comments to this (unfortunately closed) question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306020/c-static-analyzer-to-detect-specific-type-casts

Comment: @Raxvan: Any version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [C++ programming language, 3rd edition](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd.html), appendix C.6, namely "Implicit Type Conversion", Bjarne Stroustrup classifies conversions as *promotions* and *conversions*: the first ones "preserve values" (that's your case 2), the second ones doesn't (case 1).

About *conversions*, he says that "The fundamental types can be converted into each other in a bewildering number of ways. In my opinion, too many conversions are allowed." and "A compiler can warn about many questionable conversions. Fortunately, many compilers actually do."

*promotions* on the other side are safe, and it seems like a compiler is not supposed to give a warning for them.

Compiler warnings are usually not mandatory. Usually in the C++ [drafts and final ANSI documents](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) it is reported that "implementers should issue a warning" where suggested: you can check it yourself for further information if needed.

EDITED: added C++11 note:

In [The C++ programming language, 4th edition](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html), the appendix of the 3rd edition has been reported and extended as section 10.5, "Implicit Type Conversion" again.

Being the previous considerations the same, C++11 more precisely define "narrowing conversions" and adds up the {}-initializer notation (6.3.5), with which truncations lead to a compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using gcc have you tried -Wall -Wextra  basically check this page
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

If it is not GCC please post the compiler details.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visual C++ would give a warning about the narrowing conversion from `A*` to `bool`.

[See Compiler Warning C4800](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx)

Promotion on the other hand is not a "dangerous" conversion, because it's impossible to lose data.

EDIT: Demonstration

```
C:\Users\Ben>copy con test.cpp
bool f( void ) { return new int(); }
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Users\Ben>cl /c /W4 test.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
test.cpp(1) : warning C4800: 'int *' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (
performance warning)
```

Comment: Pretty sure that warning only applies to int and friends, and not pointers, as they are explicitly intended to be checkable for NULL.

Comment: @DeadMG: It doesn't occur in a boolean context such as an `if` or `while` statement, only when actually generating a `bool` variable from the value.

Comment: Promotion from `long` to `double` is generally quietly allowed, and it can lose precision.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you cannot control implicit conversion between
primitive types: it's mandated by the standard and any compliant
compiler will just perform it silently.

Are you sure an approach like BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF won't work in your
problem? A class with no virtual member functions and just one primitive
data member is basically nothing more than a POD data type.  You can
just follow the same approach and only allow conversion to the base
primitive type; example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

struct controlled_int {
  // allow creation from int
  controlled_int(int x) : value_(x) { };
  controlled_int& operator=(int x) { value_ = x; return *this; };
  // disallow assignment from bool; you might want to use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT instead
  controlled_int& operator=(bool b) { throw std::logic_error("Invalid assignment of bool to controlled_int"); return *this; };

  // creation from bool shouldn't happen silently
  explicit controlled_int(bool b) : value_(b) { };

  // conversion to int is allowed
  operator int() { return value_; };

  // conversion to bool errors out; you might want to use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT instead

  operator bool() { throw std::logic_error("Invalid conversion of controlled_int to bool"); };

  private:
    int value_;
};

int main()
{
  controlled_int a(42);

  // This errors out:
  // bool b = a;

  // This gives an error as well:
  //a = true;

  std::cout << "Size of controlled_int: " << sizeof(a) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Size of int: " << sizeof(int) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just because a compiler has to allow the conversion doesn't mean it will do so silently.  Some compilers DO produce warnings for conversions that are permitted by the standard yet "dangerous" (i.e. narrowing conversions of various kinds).  For example, I believe [MSVC++ does produce a warning for the conversion from `A*` to `bool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the available static analysis tools, programs like clint or C++ equivalents, or one of the commercially available tools. Many of these tools can pick out problematic implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom clang plugin to diagnose your problems. We do a lot of this in the LibreOffice code. Come browse our source if you want inspiration at http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/compilerplugins/clang