# g++ compiler and implicit conversion

Tags: c++, g++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I'm using g++ for compiling my C++ program, but I want to stop the implicit conversion between type like int and dooble for example:
I have a function that use  a double as parameter, but when I send in this function's parameter an int, the compilation pass without error or warning.

so that is my question, how to stop the implicit conversions??

thanks.

Comment: This is part of the language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warnings or errors for C++ implicit conversion of primitives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477139/warnings-or-errors-for-c-implicit-conversion-of-primitives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot avoid implicit conversion from lower to higher type. However you can do vice-versa
if your compiler supports C++0x.

```
void func(int x){}

int main()
{
   func({2.3}); // error: narrowing
}
```

Comment: I found a flag that send a warning (-Wconversion) however the direction of conversion. but I'm still searching for how to send an error.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: yes that works without an error message, but that is fine.
thanks guys.

Comment: I don't get this. Even if you call func({2}), g++ -std=c++0x still returns an error. The compiler can't convert from an initialiser_list to an int, whatever is in the list.

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: Not on my computer! (g++ 4.4.0 for mingw32.) C:\Temp>g++ -std=c++0x foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:5: error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'int' for argument '1' to 'void func(int)'

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void func(T t);

void func(double d)
{
    std::cout << "D:" << d << "\n";
}


int main()
{
    func(2.3);   // OK
    func(2);     // Fails at compile time.
}
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this way and it works, but I think that I'll use -Werror=conversion flag in my makefile. it's more simple and did the job.

Comment: Subtle difference: fails at linking time, not compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I think Martin's answer is the way to go.
It can find the conversion at link time.
If you have to find at compile time, you can add `static_assert` or
a similar one to the function template:

```
template<typename T>
void func( T ) {
  //static_assert( sizeof( T ) == 0, "..." ); // if you can use static_assert
  int a[ (sizeof( T ) == 0) ? 1 : -1 ];
}
```

Hope this helps.