# C++ - compilation error for all implicit conversion

Tags: c++

Is there a compiler flag that logs warning / error in case of any implicit conversions - like int32_t to uint32_t.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>


using ::std::int32_t;
using ::std::uint32_t;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   int32_t x = 9;

    uint32_t i = x;

    std::cout << " " << x << " " << i << std::flush << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wconversion -Wpedantic cast.cpp
```

I get no issues / warning / error during compilation - is there a way it can achieved.

Comment: That's probably not a very good example as the compiler can see that `9` doesn't cause conversion errors.

Comment: [You should not tag in title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: Thanks - I understand your point but is there a way that C++ compiler throws a warning / error in such implicit conversions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warnings or errors for C++ implicit conversion of primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477139/warnings-or-errors-for-c-implicit-conversion-of-primitives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uint32_t i = x;
```

Signed int type to unsigned int type conversion is well defined in C++.

**(C++11, §4.7 ¶2)**

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least
>   unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n
>   is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). — end note ]

Comment: Thanks - can you please explain a bit more on C++ rule stated above and any technique to let compiler state warning / error during compilation?

Comment: Rule means converting a positive signed int to unsigned int of same width is not a problem. Converting negative signed int to unsigned int of same width is same as adding pow(2, width in bits).

Comment: I think -Wall -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion fixes the issue - thanks for the lead

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a compiler that provides such a flag (though it's always possible I've missed one).

Lacking it, you could build a little template that will make such implicit conversions impossible in at least a few obvious situations:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using ::std::int32_t;
using ::std::uint32_t;

template <class T>
class holder {
    T value;
public:
    holder(T value) : value(value) {}
    operator T&() { return value; }
    operator T() const { return value; }
    holder &operator=(holder const &other) { value = other.value; return *this; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    holder<int32_t> x = 9;

    holder<uint32_t> i = x;

    ++i;

    std::cout << " " << x << " " << i << "\n";
}
```

Attempting to compile with g++ gives:

```
trash9.cpp:20:23: error: conversion from 'holder<int>' to non-scalar type 'holder<unsigned int>' requested
  holder<uint32_t> i = x;
                       ^
```

If, however, we change the second to `holder<int32_t> i = x;` it all works fine and acts as expected.

This suffices for the demo code you've given, but won't work in all situations. In particular, an implicit conversion in the course of evaluating an expression will still be allowed:

```
void use(holder<uint32_t> v) {
    std::cout << v;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    holder<int32_t> x = 9;

    holder<int32_t> i = x;

    use(i | 1u);
}
```

If you want to prevent conversions in cases like that as well, you can do it, but it's going to be a lot more work--you'll need to remove the `operator T` and `operator T&` from the code above, and then implement all the operators you do want to support. That would/will probably be tedious to the point that it's at least mildly painful, but you might find it acceptable anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the information - would the template version also solve for a function returning int32_t to an uint32_t variable? uint32_t x = fn(..) returning int32_t

Comment: If you used `holder<uint32_t> x = fn(...);` and `fn` was defined to return an `int32_t`, then yes, the code would be rejected (i.e., wouldn't compile).

Comment: I think -Wall -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion fixes the issue